# Syntax error when checking out a local branch

Tags: git

To confirm I have the branch I used:

```
$ git branch
  develop
* Stephen
```

Then when I try to checkout the branch to push it as a remote branch I get this error:

```
$ git checkout <Stephen>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

I am just trying to push to a remote origin so if this is the wrong way to do it please tell me thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you including the `<>`s for real? That's the problem, I would think. `<` and `>` have a special meaning for bash. Try

```
git checkout Stephen
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `<Stephen>` as a branch name. You have to use `Stephen`
as a branch name.
You should try this command.

`git checkout Stephen`